# Cannot use mongodb/mongodb's latest version 1.13.1 as it requires ext-mongodb ^1.14.0 which is missing from your platform

Tags: laravel, mongodb, composer-php

hello i am new on composer mongodb, now i am installing mongodb on my `COMMAND PROMPT`
but it gives me error message

**`composer require mongodb/mongodb`**

error:

```
Cannot use mongodb/mongodb's latest version 1.13.1 as it requires ext-mongodb ^1.14.0 which is missing from your platform.

In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 313:

  Package mongodb/mongodb has requirements incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version:
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.13.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.14.0 but it is not present.
```

my php version is PHP 8.1.10

i already tried this but it's not working

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs

composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

message of this it said NO Publishable resource

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^1.13 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update mongodb/mongodb
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   INFO  Discovering packages.  

  jenssegers/mongodb ................................................................................. DONE  
  laravel/sail ....................................................................................... DONE  
  laravel/sanctum .................................................................................... DONE  
  laravel/tinker ..................................................................................... DONE  
  nesbot/carbon ...................................................................................... DONE  
  nunomaduro/collision ............................................................................... DONE  
  nunomaduro/termwind ................................................................................ DONE  
  spatie/laravel-ignition ............................................................................ DONE  

82 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force

   INFO  No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].

No security vulnerability advisories found
```

Comment: "No publishable resources for tag"  is a message that is not related to Composer itself. Maybe you should decouple the two problems? Also, don't expect that `mongodb/mongodb` in v 1.13 works with anything else than the version of `ext-mongodb` that is listed there. Why not use any older version of that package instead?

Comment: i just downloaded PECL library for mongodb php and i extracted it then i copy pasted the mongodb.dll on php ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable mongodb extension in your php.ini file.
Locate the php.ini file, open it and add this line: `extension = mongodb.so;`

The php.ini file is located where your php is installes. For example on Windows it can be C:/php/php.ini

Comment: where i am going to put that code.  can i put that at the first line?

Comment: already solved thank you for the clue